# Why both p-values and confidence intervals for hypothesis testing of paramters?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value

I'm learning about hypothesis testing linear regression parameters. Specifically, the usual model of $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_i + \epsilon_i.$ I'm having trouble with interpreting the typical results of fitting this model to data.

My book has an example where and estimate for $\beta_1$ is 3.5702. The resulting 95 percent confidence interval is $2.85 \le \beta_1 \le 4.29$. My understanding is that this allows us to conclude that $\beta_1 \ne 0$ since $0$ does not fall within this interval.

The results also provide a p-value that is very, very close to 0. This also allows us to conlude $\beta_1 \ne 0$.

If this is correct, then why do we need both a confidence interval and a p-value? Can they ever give contradicting results? Am I missing something big here?

Answer (score 0):

A 95% CI and a p value below 0.05 (or other such as 99 and .01) both allow you to conclude either a) Reject the null or b) Fail to reject the null at the given %.

However, each gives other info as well.

P values can be given precisely and the output from most programs gives this. E.g. $p = 0.0283$.  To get this from CIs, you would have to try a lot of values!

On the other hand, CIs give you a range of values, which p values do not.

Answer (score -1):

CIs give us a range estimate for value of parameters. Meanwhile, p-values allow us to reach conclusion such as whether a parameter is non zero, or positive. Moreover, p-values have more general usage, eg in all use cases where hypothesis testing involved.

Comment: As outlined in the OP, it is the other way round: based on confidence intervals, you get a lot of information on the paramter *and* do hypotheses tests, while p values are *only* useful for testing hypotheses. Thus, confidence intervals have more general usage than p values.